# Pytorch: How to backward only a part of a recursive tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

Assume I have

```
result = mynet1(input)

calculated_value1 = result
calculated_value2 = calculated_value1 * result
```

and I want to only derive `result` using backward, in the `calculated_value2` expression, but not the inner `result` which comes from `calculated_value1`

Meaning, **I want**

```
calculated_value2.backward()
```

to refer to `calculated_value1` as a constant, even though it depends on `result`, so that the gradient would only depend on `result` once, rather that on `result^2`.

Obviously, result.detach() won't do the trick, because then the entire expression would have no parameters to optimize.

**How can I achieve the described behavior?**

---

*Clarification of intent:*

I intend to implement [section 13.5 of this book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf)

[image]

In which `delta` depends on `V`, but is not being derived, while `V` itself IS being derived.

---

Also, if there is a more suitable name for this question, please tell me so that I could change it.

Comment: calculated_value1 = result.detach()
calculated_value2 = calculated_value1 * result

detach only the first time you use result, now you compute the gradient only for result in the second expression. You can check that with with https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html?highlight=grad#torch.Tensor.requires_grad

Comment: @pierrom could you explain please?

Comment: Can you explain why it is wrong. I mean checking `calculated_value1.requires_grad` will give you False

Comment: I thought that because detaching from the graph would then make `result` also detached, thus backward wouldn't work at all, even on `calculated_value2`.
Did I get it wrong? Is a new variable returned, which does not reference the old one, and that detaching the new one won't make the old one detached?

Comment: Yepp you actually found the solution. You can see that by writing a simple script just compute `x = torch.tensor(2.0, requires_grad=True)` then `y = x` or `y=x.detach()` then `z = y * x` then `z.backward()` and finally `print(x.grad)`. In both cases you will get the gradient for x, showing that you didn't detach z from x, but the result are different for each case.

Comment: It returns a new Tensor, detached from the current graph, but uses the same data tensor.

Comment: @Gulzar Could you explain how your code example relates to the algorithm from the screenshot? There it is more like: `v = critic(state); td_error = ... - v; (-v).backward(); critic.weights.grad *= td_error;` I.e. there is no `results**2` (or `v**2`) in there. The computation `v = critic(state)` creates a node in the graph and then `td_error = ...` creates another node branching of from the previous. Calling `(-v).backward()` computes the gradient from the previous node on and detaches the graph. Then you can simply scale the gradient by `td_error`.

Comment: The problem was actually with the v(s) which is contained in delta. I had to detach delta to get it as just a value, while only v(s) gets derived

Comment: Maybe i really did not have to detach. I am just getting started with pytorch…